# matplotlib changing line color with rcParams

Tags: python, matplotlib

I just learned about the `matplotlib.rcParams` feature and so I tried to plot a very simple graph.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [1,2,3,4,5]
y = [5,3,7,9,2]

plt.rcParams['lines.color'] = 'r'
plt.rcParams['lines.linewidth'] = 3.0

plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

The resulting plot has increased linewidth but the color remains unchanged. The line is still blue.
When I check the `plt.rcParams['lines.color']` value, it prints `'r'`. 
I'm using `matplotlib version 1.3.1` with `32-bit Python 2.7.6`.

Am I doing something wrong ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in http://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html , it has no affect on plot()

*# lines.color       : blue    # has no affect on plot(); see axes.color_cycle*

Instead, this works:

```
plt.rcParams['axes.color_cycle']='r'
plt.rcParams['lines.linewidth'] = 3.0

plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 6):

Starting from matplotlib 1.5, mpl.rcParams['axes.color_cycle'] is deprecated. You should use axes.prop_cycle:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.rcParams['axes.prop_cycle'] = mpl.cycler(color=["r", "#e94cdc", "0.7"])
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure when the `line.color` is used. But when plotting like you do, the colors for lines are taken from the `axes.color_cycle` setting. This can be a single color, but is usually (and by default), a list of multiple colors.

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5]
y = [5,3,7,9,2]

plt.rcParams['lines.linewidth'] = 3.0
plt.rcParams['axes.color_cycle'] = ['r', 'grey']

# default cycle is: `['b', 'g', 'r', 'c', 'm', 'y', 'k']`

plt.plot(x, y)
plt.plot(y, x)
```

[image]